# Dynamically Adding A Chart into A Combo Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have implemented that example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo without pie chart. I want to add it dynamically after a time later. How can I add a chart into a combo chart dynamically at HighCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look the demo you will see that the `pie chart` isn't a chart, it's just a `serie`.
So, to add a serie you have to use `addSeries` passing thrue parameter all the `pie serie`, like the following.

```
    chart.addSeries({
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Total consumption',
        data: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            y: 13,
            color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
            },
        {
            name: 'John',
            y: 23,
            color: '#AA4643' // John's color
            },
        {
            name: 'Joe',
            y: 19,
            color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
            }],
        center: [100, 80],
        size: 100,
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcGb9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charts.push` as shown in this url http://calibrate.be/labs/exporting-highcharts-js-pdf-docx-tcpdf-and-phpword

Let me know if you can't have this to work.

**EDIT:** You will need to define charts as `var charts = [];` as global variable. And this has not been tested by me.

Comment: I think addSeries() does the same thing?

Comment: It doens't make sense, `.push` will not solve the problem because he wants to add it dynamically.

Comment: Well it adds new chart. and addSeries() adds a new series to an existing chart. So if your question is to add a new chart charts.push is the thing and if you want to add series to existing chart than addSeries() is what you are looking for...